# ros noetic rviz motion planning fps drop, high cpu

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, motionplanning

I have a ros package called "robot_arm_v4" which works fine without rviz but after starting rviz and adding "MotionPlanning" a cpu issue occurs and fps starts to drop.

If I disable "MotionPlanning", this problem disappears.

this problem does not happen in melodic (xubuntu 18.04) only noetic (xubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade: ros-noetic-moveit-ros-visualization:amd64 (1.1.12-1focal.20230524.164446, 1.1.13-2focal.20230801.165224)

solved my problem

[#3478](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/commit/e6ef31811bc8354e61e247e1a4d5df7156584f38)